# Centering of pdf_tex image (from Inkscape)

Tags: graphics, pdftex, inkscape, center

I'd like to center an Inkscape image.
But `\centering` does not help, my code:

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn,
    bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

%%% ------- Inkscape Import ---------------------
\usepackage{import}

%%%----- PDF Format -----------------------------
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[pdftex,pdfpagelabels,bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,
    bookmarksopenlevel      = 1,
    pdfstartpage                    = 1,
    pdfstartview                    = FitV, 
    pdfpagelayout                   = SinglePage,
    plainpages                      = false,
    hypertexnames                   = false,
    colorlinks                      = true, 
    linkcolor                           = black,
    citecolor                           = black,
    urlcolor                            = black
]{hyperref}

%%%----- Pakete ---------------------------------
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.2cm,right=2.2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}           % Grafiken einbinden
\usepackage{xcolor}                             % Farben ermöglichen
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfig}
                    
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{normalsize}       
        \import{./}{Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy.pdf_tex}
    \end{normalsize}
    \caption{Elektrisches Netzwerk einer Permanentmagnet-Synchronmaschine}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The image always appears on the left side.
**EDIT**:
The Inkscape-file looks like this:

[image]

and I export it to a `.pdf_tex`-file like this:

[image]

This is currently the result
[image]

and its `pdf`-file (`Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy.pdf`):[image]

**EDIT**: This is my `svg`-file with default page-size:
[Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy.svg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8bgkosicka5qard/Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy.svg?dl=0)

And this is the one with modified page-size (size of object):
[Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy_mod.svg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vlwxedo5y82qu9/Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy_mod.svg?dl=0)

Comment: We can't process your MWE as we do not have your file "Ersatz..." Use a generally available graphic. (I think that the `mwe` class provides them???).

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, when I try your code but with my own `.pdf_tex` file the `\centering` command indeed causes the figure to be centered. Maybe your figure has a lot of empty space on the right? Exporting using the `size of exported object` option in Inkscape might help if you are not doing that already.

Comment: How can I attach the `pdf_tex` file?

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Without checking, maybe `\begin{normalsize}...\end{normalsize}` could be a cause of your problem as the usage as an environment is invalid. It is a command and has to be used as `\normalsize`. If scoping is needed, you should go with `\begingroup\normalsize...\endgroup`

Just for completeness, maybe you could give package `svg` a try.

Comment: Unfortunately both `\begingroup\normalsize...\endgroup` and the use of the `svg` (`... \includesvg{Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy.svg} ...`) package don't work.

Comment: You could try to use `\fbox{\includesvg{Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy.svg}}` just to visualize the bounding box. Maybe you have to clip your original SVG file and/or use `\svgsetup{inkscapearea=page}`. And while you are debugging `\svgsetup{inkscape=force}` would be a reasonable setting.

Comment: Can you check `Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy.pdf`, so not the `.pdf_tex` file but the associated pdf file, and see how wide it is? Just open that pdf in a pdf viewer and check the page boundary visually. It could be that Inkscape gets confused by the long labels in the source and makes the figure wider than it really is.

Comment: I edited my post. Both the bounding and the resulting `pdf`-file show that there is much white space on the right side.

Comment: @Marijn thanks for clarification, that's why I suggested using `\fbox{...}` and pointed to `inkscapearea=page`. @Domi1908 you probably would have to reduce the page size of your SVG file on the right border matching the width of the rendered label beside your voltage source

Comment: So I have to do this in my export to `pdf_tex` settings?

Comment: Setting the page size for your SVG file has to be done directly in Inkscape. This size is used for the export to PDF afterwards, where would have to choose "Seitengröße des Dokumentes verwenden". If you are using package `svg` this export setting corresponds to `inkscapearea=page`

Comment: Your posted SVG file has the default page size, you didn't change it as recommended! Alternatively, you could use placeholders like suggested in @Marijn's answer

Comment: Yes, I added the one with the size of the object. But as I said below, I tried both methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cropping the original SVG file (attached below) as suggested multiple times, all works as expected and gives the desired result:
[image: centered picture]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\iftutex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{svg}
\svgsetup{inkscape=force}
\svgsetup{inkscape=page}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{\includesvg{Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy_mod.svg}}
  \caption{Elektrisches Netzwerk einer Permanentmagnet-Synchronmaschine}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Inkscape screenshot]

`Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy_mod.svg` with adopted page size using Inkscape.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   width="95mm"
   height="34.5mm"
   viewBox="0 0 95 34.5"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="1.1.2 (b8e25be833, 2022-02-05)"
   sodipodi:docname="Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy_mod.svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker12710"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path12708" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow2Mstart"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       inkscape:collect="always">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path6156" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker10578"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInM"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.4)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path10576" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow2Lstart"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(1.1,0,0,1.1,1.1,0)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path6150" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker10260"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleOutM"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.4)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path10258" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker9974"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInL"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.8)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path9972" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="TriangleInL"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInL"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.8)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path6265" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker7734"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInM"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.4)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path7732" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker7598"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mend"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round"
         id="path7596" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow2Mend"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mend"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path6159" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker7358"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInM"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.4)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path7356" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker7214"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lend"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(-0.8,0,0,-0.8,-10,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path6135" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker7115"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInM"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.4)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path7113" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker7021"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInM"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.4)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path7019" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Sstart"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Sstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.2,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path6144" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Send"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Send"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(-0.2,0,0,-0.2,-1.2,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path6147" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Mstart"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.4,0,0,0.4,4,0)"
         style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path6138" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker3779"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lend"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(-0.8,0,0,-0.8,-10,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path3519" />
    </marker>
    <inkscape:perspective
       sodipodi:type="inkscape:persp3d"
       inkscape:vp_x="0 : -202.5 : 1"
       inkscape:vp_y="0 : 999.99992 : 0"
       inkscape:vp_z="240 : -202.5 : 1"
       inkscape:persp3d-origin="120 : -222.49999 : 1"
       id="perspective3694" />
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Lstart"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,10,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path940" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Lstart-3"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,10,0)"
         style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path940-4" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Lstart-1"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,10,0)"
         style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path940-5" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Lstart-5"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,10,0)"
         style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path940-47" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker1801"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,10,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path1799" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Lend"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lend"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(-0.8,0,0,-0.8,-10,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path943" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow2Mstart-6"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path6156-0" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow2Mstart-6-1"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path6156-0-7" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker12710-0"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path12708-0" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow2Mstart-6-1-8"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path6156-0-7-0" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.4142136"
     inkscape:cx="138.23937"
     inkscape:cy="18.031222"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     inkscape:document-rotation="0"
     showgrid="true"
     showborder="true"
     inkscape:window-width="1680"
     inkscape:window-height="1028"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     width="95mm"
     units="mm"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     height="34.494mm">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid833"
       units="mm"
       spacingx="5"
       spacingy="5"
       originx="-38.314049"
       originy="-38.679932" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Ebene 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-38.314051,-38.679931)">
    <g
       id="g2415"
       transform="matrix(1.5466132,0,0,1.5875,4.0525665,-88.275818)"
       style="stroke-width:1.01313">
      <g
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;letter-spacing:normal;word-spacing:normal;text-anchor:start;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.168856;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10.433;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="g2417"
         xml:space="preserve"
         transform="matrix(0.07142857,0,0,-0.07142857,-12.5,180)" />
    </g>
    <g
       id="g3076">
      <ellipse
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264999;stroke-miterlimit:3;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path2321-1-6-0"
         transform="scale(-1,1)"
         cx="-44.114876"
         cy="47.27393"
         rx="0.84232366"
         ry="0.86750048" />
      <g
         id="g3037"
         transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,58.175552,44.387176)"
         style="stroke-width:1.00157;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none">
        <rect
           style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.75;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.00157;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
           id="rect1313"
           width="35.433071"
           height="14.173228"
           x="21.259844"
           y="3.5433059" />
        <path
           style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.75;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.00157;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
           d="M 3.5433076,10.62992 H 21.259843 Z"
           id="path1315"
           sodipodi:nodetypes="ccc" />
        <path
           style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.75;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.00157;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
           d="M 56.692914,10.62992 H 74.409449"
           id="path1317"
           sodipodi:nodetypes="cc" />
      </g>
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265001;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 87.004074,47.199387 H 84.927436"
         id="path1870-4"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265001;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 85.900049,47.19938 H 74.100048"
         id="path5955-6" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264999;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 114.10005,55.69993 v -8.401 l -16.299997,-0.0995"
         id="path5955-6-6"
         sodipodi:nodetypes="ccc" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265002;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 114.10005,63.89893 v 8.4 L 45.000048,72.19937"
         id="path5955-9"
         sodipodi:nodetypes="ccc" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265001;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-mid:url(#marker12710)"
         d="M 59.900051,47.199222 H 54.900049 44.900051"
         id="path7342" />
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;line-height:0%;font-family:'DejaVu Serif';-inkscape-font-specification:'DejaVu Serif Italic';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         x="66.468529"
         y="43.776089"
         id="text3696-2-3-5-9-5-8-5-8"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           x="66.468529"
           y="43.776089"
           style="font-size:4.23333px;line-height:1.25;stroke-width:0.264583px"
           id="tspan1437-5-5-2-8">$R_{\mathrm{s}}$</tspan></text>
      <ellipse
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264999;stroke-miterlimit:3;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path2321-1-6-0-0"
         transform="scale(-1,1)"
         cx="-44.114876"
         cy="72.173927"
         rx="0.84232366"
         ry="0.86750048" />
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;line-height:0%;font-family:'DejaVu Serif';-inkscape-font-specification:'DejaVu Serif Italic';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         x="120.99828"
         y="60.824192"
         id="text3696-2-3-5-9-5-8-5-8-3"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           x="120.99828"
           y="60.824192"
           style="font-size:4.23333px;line-height:1.25;stroke-width:0.264583px"
           id="tspan1437-5-5-2-8-6">$\omega_{\mathrm{el}}\bm{J}\bm{\psi}_{\mathrm{s}}^{dq}$</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;line-height:0%;font-family:'DejaVu Serif';-inkscape-font-specification:'DejaVu Serif Italic';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         x="51.636284"
         y="45.039089"
         id="text3696-2-3-5-9-5-8-5-8-6"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           x="51.636284"
           y="45.039089"
           style="font-size:4.23333px;line-height:1.25;stroke-width:0.264583px"
           id="tspan1437-5-5-2-8-8">$\bm{i}_{\mathrm{s}}^{dq}$</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;line-height:0%;font-family:'DejaVu Serif';-inkscape-font-specification:'DejaVu Serif Italic';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         x="38.136284"
         y="60.238937"
         id="text3696-2-3-5-9-5-8-5-8-6-4"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           x="38.136284"
           y="60.238937"
           style="font-size:4.23333px;line-height:1.25;stroke-width:0.264583px"
           id="tspan1437-5-5-2-8-8-9">$\bm{u}_{\mathrm{s}}^{dq}$</tspan></text>
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;line-height:0%;font-family:'DejaVu Serif';-inkscape-font-specification:'DejaVu Serif Italic';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         x="87.95295"
         y="41.644089"
         id="text3696-2-3-5-9-5-8-5-8-6-4-8"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           x="87.95295"
           y="41.644089"
           style="font-size:4.23333px;line-height:1.25;stroke-width:0.264583px"
           id="tspan1437-5-5-2-8-8-9-4">$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\bm{\psi}_{\mathrm{s}}^{dq}$</tspan></text>
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264999;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:3;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:url(#Arrow2Mstart)"
         d="M 44.161878,68.841162 V 50.32893"
         id="path2186-4-8-4-2-4-0-1" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264999;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:3;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:url(#Arrow2Mstart-6-1)"
         d="M 97.24882,43.897974 H 86.446049"
         id="path2186-4-8-4-2-4-0-1-8-0" />
      <g
         id="g2463"
         transform="translate(46.100178,-5.201062)">
        <ellipse
           cy="-67.942657"
           cx="64.999992"
           id="circle1868-7-3"
           style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265001;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
           rx="4.1146255"
           ry="4.1532826"
           transform="rotate(90)" />
        <path
           sodipodi:nodetypes="cscsc"
           inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
           id="path1901-1-1"
           d="m 70.000002,65.000001 c 0,0.573451 -0.460555,1.038324 -1.02866,1.038324 -0.568115,0 -1.028652,-0.464873 -1.028652,-1.038322 0,-0.573453 -0.460544,-1.038328 -1.028669,-1.038328 -0.568104,0 -1.028647,0.464875 -1.028647,1.038328"
           style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265001;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" />
      </g>
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.75;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 87.282722,47.199221 c 0,0 0,-1.875 1.13623,-1.875 1.13622,0 1.13622,1.875 1.13622,1.875 0,-1.875 1.13622,-1.875 1.13622,-1.875 1.13622,0 1.13622,1.875 1.13622,1.875 0,-1.875 1.13622,-1.875 1.13622,-1.875 1.13622,0 1.13622,1.875 1.13622,1.875 0,-1.875 1.13622,-1.875 1.13622,-1.875 0,0 1.13623,0 1.13623,1.875 0,0 1.70433,0 1.70433,0 m -12.49844,0 h 1.70433"
         id="path1317-2"
         sodipodi:nodetypes="czccccccsccc" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264999;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:3;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:url(#Arrow2Mstart-6-1-8)"
         d="M 120,65 V 54.197226"
         id="path2186-4-8-4-2-4-0-1-8-0-3" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In a (now deleted) comment the OP asked for a Latex-only solution. This can be done with the `circuitikz` package. The various components can be drawn using the `to[component=label]` syntax, positioning can be done using `++(x,y)`. Note that the positioning is relative using this syntax. For more details see the circuitikz [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf).

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[european resistors,american inductors]
\draw (0,0) node (start) {}
% arrow with label above
to[short, i=$\bm{i}^{dq}_{S}$, o-] ++(2,0)
% resistor (european notation)
to[R=$R_S$] ++(1.5,0)
% inductor (american notation). Label raised a bit to make room for arrow later
to[L=\raisebox{7pt}{$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\bm{\psi}_{\mathrm{s}}^{dq}$},name=indtop] ++(4,0)
% voltage source
to[sV=$\omega_{\mathrm{el}}\bm{J}\bm{\psi}_{\mathrm{s}}^{dq}$] ++(0,-2)
% line to end
to[short,-o] ++(-7.5,0)
node (end) {};
% circuitikz doesn't seem to support arrows on top of an inductor, drawing manually
\draw[-Triangle]([yshift=4pt]indtop.north west) -- ([yshift=4pt]indtop.north east);
% arrow between start and end, shortened on both sides
\draw[-Triangle,shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] (start) -- (end);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Elektrisches Netzwerk einer Permanentmagnet-Synchronmaschine}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by mrpiggi, one way (probably the easiest) is to fit the page around the actual diagram in Inkscape with the label outside the page boundary and then export using the page size (Seitengröße des Dokuments verwenden).

Another way is to put small placeholder macros in Inkscape, for example as follows:

[image]

Export as normal, using the size of the objects (Größe des exportierten Objekts). This will make sure the pdf file does not stretch so far to the right. Then define these placeholders in your LaTeX document:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \def\ltop{$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{D}t}\psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{dq}$}
    \def\lrt{$\omega_{\mathrm{el}}J\psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{dq}$}
    \centering
    \begin{normalsize}       
        \import{./}{your_figure.pdf_tex}
    \end{normalsize}
    \caption{Elektrisches Netzwerk einer Permanentmagnet-Synchronmaschine}
\end{figure}
```

Result:

[image]

It also works with the svg from the question with the real diagram. Here the modified SVG code after putting in the placeholders:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 296.99999"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="1.1.2 (0a00cf5339, 2022-02-04)"
   sodipodi:docname="Ersatzschaltbild_PMSM_dq_KoSy.svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker12710"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path12708" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow2Mstart"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       inkscape:collect="always">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path6156" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker10578"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInM"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.4)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path10576" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow2Lstart"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(1.1,0,0,1.1,1.1,0)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path6150" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker10260"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleOutM"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.4)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path10258" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker9974"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInL"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.8)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path9972" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="TriangleInL"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInL"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.8)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path6265" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker7734"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInM"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.4)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path7732" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker7598"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mend"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round"
         id="path7596" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow2Mend"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mend"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path6159" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker7358"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInM"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.4)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path7356" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker7214"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lend"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(-0.8,0,0,-0.8,-10,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path6135" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker7115"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInM"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.4)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path7113" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker7021"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="TriangleInM"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(-0.4)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 5.77,0 -2.88,5 V -5 Z"
         id="path7019" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Sstart"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Sstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.2,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path6144" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Send"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Send"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(-0.2,0,0,-0.2,-1.2,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path6147" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Mstart"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.4,0,0,0.4,4,0)"
         style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path6138" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker3779"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lend"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(-0.8,0,0,-0.8,-10,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path3519" />
    </marker>
    <inkscape:perspective
       sodipodi:type="inkscape:persp3d"
       inkscape:vp_x="0 : 59.999993 : 1"
       inkscape:vp_y="0 : 999.99997 : 0"
       inkscape:vp_z="240 : 59.999993 : 1"
       inkscape:persp3d-origin="120 : 39.999994 : 1"
       id="perspective3694" />
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Lstart"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,10,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path940" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Lstart-3"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,10,0)"
         style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path940-4" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Lstart-1"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,10,0)"
         style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path940-5" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Lstart-5"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,10,0)"
         style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path940-47" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker1801"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,10,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path1799" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow1Lend"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lend"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="matrix(-0.8,0,0,-0.8,-10,0)"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 Z"
         id="path943" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow2Mstart-6"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path6156-0" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow2Mstart-6-1"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path6156-0-7" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker12710-0"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path12708-0" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="Arrow2Mstart-6-1-8"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow2Mstart"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         transform="scale(0.6)"
         d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path6156-0-7-0" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.4142136"
     inkscape:cx="341.88612"
     inkscape:cy="234.40589"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     inkscape:document-rotation="0"
     showgrid="true"
     showborder="true"
     inkscape:window-width="1846"
     inkscape:window-height="1016"
     inkscape:window-x="74"
     inkscape:window-y="27"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     width="34.494mm"
     units="mm"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid833"
       units="mm"
       spacingx="5"
       spacingy="5"
       originx="-19.213999"
       originy="-16.381" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Ebene 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-19.214001,-16.381)">
    <g
       id="g2415"
       transform="matrix(1.5466132,0,0,1.5875,4.0525665,-88.275818)"
       style="stroke-width:1.01313">
      <g
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;letter-spacing:normal;word-spacing:normal;text-anchor:start;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.168856;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10.433;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="g2417"
         xml:space="preserve"
         transform="matrix(0.07142857,0,0,-0.07142857,-12.5,180)" />
    </g>
    <ellipse
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264999;stroke-miterlimit:3;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="path2321-1-6-0"
       transform="scale(-1,1)"
       cx="-44.114876"
       cy="47.27393"
       rx="0.84232366"
       ry="0.86750048" />
    <g
       id="g3037"
       transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,58.175552,44.387176)"
       style="stroke-width:1.00157;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none">
      <rect
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.75;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.00157;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="rect1313"
         width="35.433071"
         height="14.173228"
         x="21.259844"
         y="3.5433059" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.75;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.00157;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 3.5433076,10.62992 H 21.259843 Z"
         id="path1315"
         sodipodi:nodetypes="ccc" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.75;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.00157;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 56.692914,10.62992 H 74.409449"
         id="path1317"
         sodipodi:nodetypes="cc" />
    </g>
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265001;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="M 87.004074,47.199387 H 84.927436"
       id="path1870-4"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265001;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="M 85.900049,47.19938 H 74.100048"
       id="path5955-6" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264999;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 114.10005,55.69993 v -8.401 l -16.299997,-0.0995"
       id="path5955-6-6"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccc" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265002;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 114.10005,63.89893 v 8.4 L 45.000048,72.19937"
       id="path5955-9"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccc" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265001;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-mid:url(#marker12710)"
       d="M 59.900051,47.199222 H 54.900049 44.900051"
       id="path7342" />
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;line-height:0%;font-family:'DejaVu Serif';-inkscape-font-specification:'DejaVu Serif Italic';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="66.468529"
       y="43.776089"
       id="text3696-2-3-5-9-5-8-5-8"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         x="66.468529"
         y="43.776089"
         style="font-size:4.23333px;line-height:1.25;stroke-width:0.264583px"
         id="tspan1437-5-5-2-8">$R_{\mathrm{s}}$</tspan></text>
    <ellipse
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264999;stroke-miterlimit:3;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="path2321-1-6-0-0"
       transform="scale(-1,1)"
       cx="-44.114876"
       cy="72.173927"
       rx="0.84232366"
       ry="0.86750048" />
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;line-height:0%;font-family:'DejaVu Serif';-inkscape-font-specification:'DejaVu Serif Italic';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="120.99828"
       y="60.824192"
       id="text3696-2-3-5-9-5-8-5-8-3"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         x="120.99828"
         y="60.824192"
         style="font-size:4.23333px;line-height:1.25;stroke-width:0.264583px"
         id="tspan1437-5-5-2-8-6">\lrt</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;line-height:0%;font-family:'DejaVu Serif';-inkscape-font-specification:'DejaVu Serif Italic';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="51.636284"
       y="45.039089"
       id="text3696-2-3-5-9-5-8-5-8-6"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         x="51.636284"
         y="45.039089"
         style="font-size:4.23333px;line-height:1.25;stroke-width:0.264583px"
         id="tspan1437-5-5-2-8-8">$\bm{i}_{\mathrm{s}}^{dq}$</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;line-height:0%;font-family:'DejaVu Serif';-inkscape-font-specification:'DejaVu Serif Italic';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="38.136284"
       y="60.238937"
       id="text3696-2-3-5-9-5-8-5-8-6-4"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         x="38.136284"
         y="60.238937"
         style="font-size:4.23333px;line-height:1.25;stroke-width:0.264583px"
         id="tspan1437-5-5-2-8-8-9">$\bm{u}_{\mathrm{s}}^{dq}$</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:italic;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.175px;line-height:0%;font-family:'DejaVu Serif';-inkscape-font-specification:'DejaVu Serif Italic';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="87.95295"
       y="41.644089"
       id="text3696-2-3-5-9-5-8-5-8-6-4-8"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         x="87.95295"
         y="41.644089"
         style="font-size:4.23333px;line-height:1.25;stroke-width:0.264583px"
         id="tspan1437-5-5-2-8-8-9-4">\ltop</tspan></text>
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264999;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:3;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:url(#Arrow2Mstart)"
       d="M 44.161878,68.841162 V 50.32893"
       id="path2186-4-8-4-2-4-0-1" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264999;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:3;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:url(#Arrow2Mstart-6-1)"
       d="M 97.24882,43.897974 H 86.446049"
       id="path2186-4-8-4-2-4-0-1-8-0" />
    <g
       id="g2463"
       transform="translate(46.100178,-5.201062)">
      <ellipse
         cy="-67.942657"
         cx="64.999992"
         id="circle1868-7-3"
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265001;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
         rx="4.1146255"
         ry="4.1532826"
         transform="rotate(90)" />
      <path
         sodipodi:nodetypes="cscsc"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         id="path1901-1-1"
         d="m 70.000002,65.000001 c 0,0.573451 -0.460555,1.038324 -1.02866,1.038324 -0.568115,0 -1.028652,-0.464873 -1.028652,-1.038322 0,-0.573453 -0.460544,-1.038328 -1.028669,-1.038328 -0.568104,0 -1.028647,0.464875 -1.028647,1.038328"
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265001;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" />
    </g>
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.75;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 87.282722,47.199221 c 0,0 0,-1.875 1.13623,-1.875 1.13622,0 1.13622,1.875 1.13622,1.875 0,-1.875 1.13622,-1.875 1.13622,-1.875 1.13622,0 1.13622,1.875 1.13622,1.875 0,-1.875 1.13622,-1.875 1.13622,-1.875 1.13622,0 1.13622,1.875 1.13622,1.875 0,-1.875 1.13622,-1.875 1.13622,-1.875 0,0 1.13623,0 1.13623,1.875 0,0 1.70433,0 1.70433,0 m -12.49844,0 h 1.70433"
       id="path1317-2"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="czccccccsccc" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264999;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:3;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:url(#Arrow2Mstart-6-1-8)"
       d="M 120,65 V 54.197226"
       id="path2186-4-8-4-2-4-0-1-8-0-3" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me still the same result ...

Comment: I have tried both ways.

Comment: @Domi1908 I just tried this approach with your original svg, that also works. I have added the modified SVG code to the answer (and mrpiggi has added the page-cropped version to his answer) so you can test both solutions yourself. To download you just copy the svg code into a text editor and save it with `.svg` extension, then it can be opened by Inkscape.